# Why is ranges::basic_istream_view::begin() not cached?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3, std-ranges

I found that c++20 [`ranges::basic_istream_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/basic_istream_view#:%7E:text=The%20iterator%20type%20of%20basic_istream_view%20is%20move-only%3A%20it,it%20does%20not%20work%20with%20standard%20iterator%20adaptors.) is slightly different from the [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/1120609c7cb5dee9d2d216c579e935475cc39c4e/include/range/v3/view/istream.hpp) version.

The most important difference is that the `std::ranges::basic_istream_view` does not cache its `begin()`, so that each `begin()`s will return the next iterator with the value that has been read ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/T799z4Wen)):

```
auto words = std::istringstream{"today is yesterday's tomorrow"};
auto view = std::ranges::istream_view<std::string>(words);
std::cout << *view.begin() << "\n"; // today
std::cout << *view.begin() << "\n"; // is
std::cout << *view.begin() << "\n"; // yesterday's
std::cout << *view.begin() << "\n"; // tomorrow
```

Consider the following ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/czs5Pz7dd)), If I use the range-v3 version, all the three `std::ranges::find()`s will found `"is"`, but if I use the std version, `"is"` will be found only in the first call.

```
auto words = std::istringstream{"today is yesterday's tomorrow"};
auto view = std::ranges::istream_view<std::string>(words);
std::cout << *std::ranges::find(view, "is") << "\n"; // is
std::cout << *std::ranges::find(view, "is") << "\n"; // tomorrow
std::cout << *std::ranges::find(view, "is") << "\n"; // tomorrow
```

Why did the standard choose a different design from range-v3? Is there any potential defect if `begin()` is cached?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the definition of the `range` concept, in [[range.range]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.range), we have:

```cpp
template<class T>
  concept range =
    requires(T& t) {
      ranges::begin(t);   // sometimes equality-preserving (see below)
      ranges::end(t);
    };
```

where the "see below" parts are (emphasis mine):

> Given an expression `t` such that `decltype((t))` is `T&`, `T` models range only if
>
> - ...
> - if the type of `ranges​::​begin(t)` models `forward_­iterator`, `ranges​::​begin(t)` is equality-preserving.
>
> [*Note 1*: Equality preservation of both `ranges​::​begin` and `ranges​::​end` enables passing a range whose iterator type models `forward_­iterator` to multiple algorithms and making multiple passes over the range by repeated calls to `ranges​::​begin` and `ranges​::​end`. **Since `ranges​::​begin` is not required to be equality-preserving when the return type does not model `forward_­iterator`, it is possible for repeated calls to not return equal values or to not be well-defined.** — end note]

For forward ranges, you can call `ranges::begin(r)` repeatedly and expect the same answer (it is equality-preserving). For some ranges, that requires caching.

But for input-only ranges (like `istream_view`), you can call `ranges::begin(r)` exactly one time, and there are no guarantees for what happens on the second invocation.

So the difference between the two implementations isn't observable by a valid program, since by calling `begin` multiple times you're already violating the preconditions here.

---

For a more specific answer as to `istream_view`, range-v3's implementation does cache not `begin()` either. That's not the difference that's happening. And indeed, you cannot cache input iterators anyway, since they would immediately be invalidated.

The difference is rather *when* we read the first value from the stream:

- in [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/b0696c75dd8b420432c76e5d90fa133ccb423437/include/range/v3/view/istream.hpp#L84), that happens in the constructor of `istream_view`.
- in [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d25809dbfe43917b3bed9454620fcc24f04c1e03/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/ranges#L649), that happens in the call to `begin()`.

The latter is more consistent with the general Ranges model where constructing range adaptors does not actually do any work.

Answer (score 5):

input iterators are such that as soon as you have dereferenced one, you need to instantly increment it. The same is with output iterators, such as back_insert_iterator. This is something that you are just not supposed to be doing. If you need the first value cached, cache it yourself.

The reason input and output iterators need to be incremented after dereferencing is that they are by design single pass.If you have read something from a stream, you cannot read it again. Operator * actually reads from the stream. What does ++ do? Nothing! Same goes for back_insert_iterator